# Copying using Drive.Files.copy is resulting as a PDF, not Google doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm needing to use the `Drive.Files.copy` function for copying a file in Team Drives. The functionality is to copy a template Google Doc to a new file and folder.

The function below seems to copy the file, but the resulting file is a PDF (the original file is a Google Doc). It's probably something simple that I'm not seeing.

`teacherFolder` is the destination.
`learnerDoc` is original file.
`newDocc` is new file.

```
function test() {
  var newFile = {
    title: "Learner Guide - test",
    description: "New student learner guide",
    mimetype: 'application/vnd.google-apps.file',
    supportsTeamDrives: true,
    kind: "drive#user",
    includeTeamDriveItems: true
  };
  // find Teacher's Learner Guides folder
  var teacherFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1qQJhDMlHZixBO9KZkkoSNYdMuqg0vBPU');

  // create duplicate Learner Guide Template document
  var learnerDoc = DriveApp.getFileById('1g6cjUn1BWVqRAIhrOyXXsTwTmPZ4QW6qGhUAeTHJSUs');

  //var newDocc = Drive.Files.copy(newFile, learnerDoc.getId());
  var newDocc = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, learnerDoc.getBlob(), newFile);
  var DriveAppFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newDocc.id);
  teacherFolder.addFile(DriveAppFile);
  Logger.log('file = ' + newDocc.fileExtension);
}
```

How can I create a duplicate Google Doc in Team Drives and move it to a different folder?

Comment: Although I'm not sure that I could understand correctly about your situation, it seems that ``Drive.Files.copy()`` is not used in your script. If this was not your latest script, can you update it? Then, in the case of Google Docs, when the blob of file is retrieved by ``getBlob()``, the mimeType of blob becomes ``application/pdf``. I think that this is the specification of Google.

Comment: When I un-comment the Drive.Files.copy() line, an error is thrown, "File not found: 1g6cjUn1BWVqRAIhrOyXXsTwTmPZ4QW6qGhUAeTHJSUs", so I tried to insert the file.

Comment: @Tanaike copy is working. Parents is not. File not going in folderID in parents.

  var newFile = {
    "title": "Learner Guide - test",
    "description": "New student learner guide",
    "parents": [teacherFolder.getId()],
    "supportsTeamDrives": true,
    "kind": "drive#file",
    "includeTeamDriveItems": true
  };
  
  var learnerDoc = DriveApp.getFileById('1g6cjUn1BWVqRAIhrOyXXsTwTmPZ4QW6qGhUAeTHJSUs');
  var newDocc = Drive.Files.copy(newFile, learnerDoc.getId(), newFile);

Comment: Thank you for replying. Although I posted an answer for showing the modification points, I noticed that you have posted as [an another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244239/drive-files-copy-and-parents-not-working) just now. So I deleted my answer. And if you add more information of your question, please add them to your question using the edit button. Because your posted answer has not resolved your question. By updating your question, other users who have the same issue can see your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the "File not found" error is that you are attempting to access a file located in a Team Drive, but do not indicate in the optional parameters that your code knows how to handle the differences between Google Drive and Team Drives.

You have set this parameter, but you set it in the metadata that is associated with the file you are inserting/copying, and not as an optional parameter to the Drive API.

Thus, to resolve the "File not found" error, you need to change the metadata definition:

```
var newFile = {
  title: "Learner Guide - test",
  description: "New student learner guide",
  mimetype: 'application/vnd.google-apps.file',
  supportsTeamDrives: true,
  kind: "drive#user",
  includeTeamDriveItems: true
};
```

to metadata and parameters:

```
const newFile = {
  title: "Learner Guide - test",
  description: "New student learner guide",
};
const options = {
  supportsTeamDrives: true,
  includeTeamDriveItems: true
};
```

I'm not sure what you were trying to do by supplying the mimetype as a generic file (you should let the Drive API infer this for a `Copy` operation), or why you try to set the `kind` parameter, which is generally a read-only description of the contents of an API response.

With that change, you then pass optional parameters as the last call to the client library method:

```
var newDocc = Drive.Files.copy(newFile, learnerDoc.getId());
```

becomes

```
var newDocc = Drive.Files.copy(newFile, learnerDoc.getId(), options);
```

Related reading:

- [Team Drive support](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/enable-teamdrives)
- [Apps Script advanced `Drive` service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)
- [Apps Script client library method signatures](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#how_method_signatures_are_determined)
- [`Drive.Files.copy`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/copy)

Comment: Thank you @tehhowch for the details! This was exactly the problem and I'm clearer on the usage of optional parameters now. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Tanaike for your help and answers. More details on the working solution for this can be found at:

[Drive.Files.Copy and "parents" not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244239/drive-files-copy-and-parents-not-working)